# Acumatica/MYOB Advanced The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: acumatica

I have local version installed on my pc and am getting the following error which breaking the whole site, comes up with this no matter what page I go to.  I have connected to MSSQL server.  Using MySql it seems to get past this.  Please help

```
[KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.]
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException() +38
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key) +54
   MYOB.AdvancedLive.Core.License.LicenceTypeUsageDefinition.PX.Data.IPrefetchable.Prefetch() +1067
   PX.Data.PXDatabase.prefetchMethod() +205
   PX.Data.PXDatabaseProviderBase.prefetchMethod(PrefetchDelegate`1 prefetchDelegate, PXDatabaseSlot slot) +455
   PX.Data.<>c__DisplayClass29_0`1.<GetSlot>b__3(PXDatabaseSlot slot) +78
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +732
   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +189
   PX.Data.PXDatabaseProviderBase.GetSlot(String key, PrefetchDelegate`1 prefetchDelegate, Type[] tables) +1014
   PX.Data.PXDatabase.GetSlot(String key, Type[] tables) +232
   MYOB.AdvancedLive.Core.License.MYOBLicenseTypes.GetCurrentUsage(String licenceTypeID) +94
   MYOB.AdvancedLive.Core.Objects.SM.EntitlementsMaint.GetCurrentUsage(MyobLicenseEntitlementDefinition entitlement) +315
   MYOB.AdvancedLive.Core.Objects.SM.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<EntitlementsFromLicense>b__0(MyobLicenseEntitlementDefinition entitlement) +53
   System.Linq.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`3.<CombineSelectors>b__0(TSource x) +23
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +241
   MYOB.AdvancedLive.Core.License.<entitlements>d__3.MoveNext() +461
   System.Linq.<OfTypeIterator>d__95`1.MoveNext() +141
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +453
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +69
   _CustomMethod(Object , Object[] ) +67
   PX.Data.PXView.InvokeDelegate(Object[] parameters) +346
   PX.Data.PXView.Select(Object[] currents, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows) +1493
   PX.Data.PXGraph.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, Object[] currents, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows) +1474
   PX.Data.PXGraph.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows) +80
   PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments) +19764
   PX.Web.UI.PXDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments) +209
   PX.Web.UI.PXDataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments swarguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +65
   PX.Web.UI.PXGrid.PerformSelect() +1946
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +249
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +191
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +249
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +191
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +249
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +191
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +249
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +191
   PX.Web.UI.PXBoundPanel.OnAfterSelect(PXFormDataProvider provider) +179
   PX.Web.UI.PXFormDataProvider.OnDataSourceViewSelect(IEnumerable data) +587
   PX.Web.UI.PXFormDataProvider.DataBind() +384
   PX.Web.UI.PXBoundPanel.PerformSelect() +122
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +134
   PX.Web.UI.PXTab.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +37
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +200
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +297
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +297
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +297
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +297
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +297
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +7474
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems deleting all records from the licencing table has fixed the issue so far